# Rpart Plot in R

Tags: r, regression

I am doing some regression analysis on the small data I have based on the admission number where I want to see the effect of other variables on it. Regression works fine and I do get a good output but how can I build a regression Tree. Can anyone please help me! It is only giving me 1 node, not the complete tree.

data:

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021), RANK_W = c(197, 115, 98, 101, 88, 94, 103, 
128, 127, 121), RANK_Y = c(19, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 5, 10, 6, 6), GRADS = c(10276, 
10156, 10144, 10163, 10080, 9958, 9636, 9102, 8833, 8234), CPINL = c(96.04, 
98.44, 99.4, 100, 100.32, 101.7, 103.44, 106.16, 107.51, 110.39
), RENT = c(576, 576, 576, 621, 621, 621, 629, 629, 629, 662), 
    ACCOM = c(33902, 35449, 35838, 35719, 35747, 36362, 36841, 
    36882, 36797, 37675), UNEMP = c(0.54, 0.74, 0.74, 0.63, 0.57, 
    0.47, 0.34, 0.31, 0.35, 0.38), HINC = c(24800, 24800, 26000, 
    26000, 26900, 27700, 27900, 29800, 30500, 30500), Adm.Numbers = c(1660, 
    1726, 1846, 1955, 2026, 1999, 1954, 1924, 1952, 2078)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Code:

```
model <- lm(Adm.Numbers ~. - YEAR, data = FACTORS_Thesis_1_)
print(model)
summary(model)

Tree <- rpart(Adm.Numbers ~. - YEAR, data = FACTORS_Thesis_1_, method = "anova")
Tree
rpart.plot(Tree)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to plot the tree using its default settings. You can `control` these in the `rpart` function. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(rpart.plot)
Tree <- rpart(Adm.Numbers ~. - YEAR, data = FACTORS_Thesis_1_, method = "anova", control =rpart.control(minsplit =1,minbucket=1, cp=0))
rpart.plot(Tree)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>